# Youtube embedded player - show no recommendations (videos) at the end?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have an am bedded youtube video in my site, but at the end of it, Youtube displays a set of **recommendations** (other videos) which I'd like to remove since they have nothing to do with my video.

Is that possible? Can't seem to find anything gin the Youtube embedded API :(

Answer (score 4):

Just add `?rel=0` at the end of your video, `&rel=0` no longer works

Example:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hy9Cbp_yV5Y?rel=0" 
width="100%" height="100%"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: &rel=0 and ?rel=0 are the same thing. They are both query parameters. The only difference is that if it is the first query parameter you need start with ?. All subsequent parameters use &.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to attach to the player URL (http://www.youtube.com/v/Yc_J_kXaFSw) the rel=0 parameter.

The player URL will became http://www.youtube.com/v/Yc_J_kXaFSw&rel=0

The source of this information:
http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/disable%20related%20videos%20embedded%20youtube%20player

Just add `&rel=0` at the end of your video url, this should remove the recommendations.